# How to generate proxy for a Service using wsimport using a java program

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl2java, wsimport

I am writing a small framework to test SOAP services. 
for this purpose I am planning to use wsimport tool to generate proxy at runtime for the web services to test. Is there any way to execute wsimport by a java program so that I can pass the Service wsdl url taken from the user by a simple web form.

This way my program will handle multiple Serivce urls to generate proxy for them.

I know about adding an Ant task for wsimport but in my knowledge it requires for a physical path of the WSDL file which is not possible due to the dynamic nature of my application.

The other way I know to execute command prompt using Java and then executing wsimport which will again does not work in case this application will be hosted on Linux server. If someone can please suggest a better solution.